# Meilisearch or Eloquent queries?

Tags: php, laravel, meilisearch

I write api and use Laravel Scout + Meilisearch on my project. Everything is working. But I have some doubts about whether I am using meilisearch correctly. I would appreciate any help.

I know that it is possible to access meilisearch via **localhost::7700** using Meilisearch\Client,
as well as through the **search** method provided by the Searchable trait.
In case I access it via the **search** method, like this:

```
$this->query = User::search($query, function ($meili_search, string $query, array $options) use ($request, $sort_field, $sort_direction) {
   $options['offset'] = PaginatorHelper::offset($request->page ?? 1, $request->per_page);
   $options['limit'] = intval($request->per_page);
   $options['sort'] = [$sort_field .':' . $sort_direction];

   return $meili_search->search($query, $options);
});

$this->query->get();
```

I see Eloquent queries in the telescope like:

`select * from` users`where`users`.`id `in (1, 2, 3)`

But I don't understand why I see Eloquent queries if I request data via meilisearch? As if queries go to both meilisearch and mysql.

I expect data to be requested from meilisearch directly, bypassing Eloquent and the current behavior is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using it correctly. When you use get(), first it gets ids from Meilisearch database and then call a query to the datable using whereIn.

You can take a look, this is code of get method https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/10.x/src/Builder.php#L286

```
/**
 * Get the results of the search.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function get()
{
    return $this->engine()->get($this);
}
```

It calls the get method of engine, in this case, MeilisearchEngine. MeilisearchEngine extends Engine.
https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/10.x/src/Engines/Engine.php#L133

```
/**
 * Get the results of the given query mapped onto models.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Scout\Builder  $builder
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function get(Builder $builder)
{
    return $this->map(
        $builder, $this->search($builder), $builder->model
    );
}
```

Within the map method, it calls getScoutModelsByIds method
https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/10.x/src/Engines/MeilisearchEngine.php#L264

```
 * Map the given results to instances of the given model.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Scout\Builder  $builder
 * @param  mixed  $results
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function map(Builder $builder, $results, $model)
{
    if (is_null($results) || 0 === count($results['hits'])) {
        return $model->newCollection();
    }

    $objectIds = collect($results['hits'])->pluck($model->getScoutKeyName())->values()->all();

    $objectIdPositions = array_flip($objectIds);

    return $model->getScoutModelsByIds(
        $builder, $objectIds
    )->filter(function ($model) use ($objectIds) {
        return in_array($model->getScoutKey(), $objectIds);
    })->sortBy(function ($model) use ($objectIdPositions) {
        return $objectIdPositions[$model->getScoutKey()];
    })->values();
}
```

Within getScoutModelsByIds, it calls getScoutModelsByIds:
https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/10.x/src/Searchable.php#L224

```
/**
 * Get the requested models from an array of object IDs.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Scout\Builder  $builder
 * @param  array  $ids
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getScoutModelsByIds(Builder $builder, array $ids)
{
    return $this->queryScoutModelsByIds($builder, $ids)->get();
}
```

And then, queryScoutModelsByIds builds query using whereIn:

```
/**
 * Get a query builder for retrieving the requested models from an array of object IDs.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Scout\Builder  $builder
 * @param  array  $ids
 * @return mixed
 */
public function queryScoutModelsByIds(Builder $builder, array $ids)
{
    $query = static::usesSoftDelete()
        ? $this->withTrashed() : $this->newQuery();

    if ($builder->queryCallback) {
        call_user_func($builder->queryCallback, $query);
    }

    $whereIn = in_array($this->getKeyType(), ['int', 'integer']) ?
        'whereIntegerInRaw' :
        'whereIn';

    return $query->{$whereIn}(
        $this->qualifyColumn($this->getScoutKeyName()), $ids
    );
}
```

To get raw results just from Meilisearch, you can use raw method:

```
$this->query->raw();
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped a lot!
So I suppose that the get method with its whereIn queries is needed only to return the result as a collection?!

Comment: Yeah, it returns a collection of Eloquent models. Due to this, you can get more information from your database and use features of eloquent models such as relationship